Any way to make Chrome not flicker on the right size when changing window width?
I'm animating a browser windows' left edge in Electron. So the left side moves, the right side is fixed.
My problem is that everything seems to be really flickering / jumping on the right side.
It's the exact same behaviour with any Chrome window, you don't need Electron for this. Moving the right side with mouse gives super stable visuals on the left side, but moving the left side with mouse makes a flickering / jumping mess on the right side.
Is there any possible way to make the right side fixed and have the left side jump? I'm thinking maybe with some RTL tricks we could change the behaviour of the browser. Or is this hardcoded into the low-level display code of the browser?
Minimal reproducible example uploaded here
Screen recording on macOS: https://youtu.be/UM7if2LLMqE?si=vl7nfQGnlCBJP0s8

Would it be possible to add a Minimal, Reproducible Example of this phenomenon to your question? Which OS are you using?

It's any website really, you can try resizing this one right now. Moving right side -> stable left side text, moving left side -> jumping right side text. I'm using macOS.
For an example the best would be to try to make a screen recording, I'll look into it.

I'm not seeing any flickering (Chrome/Edge on Windows 11) - only the text respositioning to different lines as it needs to. I think you will have to give a small example of code for which this definitely shows the problem and say what versions of OS, type of device and version of Chrome you see this in. And do you see it on any other browser?

Yes, a screen recording would be nice. Still not sure what the exact problem is. I'm using Windows 11 as well, and don't see any particular problem when making the browser window wider or narrower by dragging its left or right edge with the mouse. Tried Firefox and Chrome.

Thanks for the example. I can confirm that I see the same as you do. I definitely wouldn't call this a flickering/jumping mess. For me the effect is a bit stronger in Chrome than in Firefox. I would say this movement is part of the normal rendering process a browser has to do. Especially because the browser is thinking about adding a vertical scroll bar. What can help a bit is to hide the scroll bar using: .container { overflow-y: hidden; }, but you'll never get rid of this completely. Also, why on earth is this a problem?

In Electron, I want to animate the browser width on the left side, which is basically not possible because of this behavior.
